# Join specific bits

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I have dto object `Data` with 2 property: `int Value` and `int Width`.
I have `list<Data> DataList`.
I have `byte[] Result`.

I need to process this list like that:

```
foeach(var data in DataList)
{
     var byteData = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Value); //result 4 bytes length a
     //Than i need to copy bits starting from hight (left) from byteData to Result, equal to data.Width.
     //So if DataList have 2 elements: DataList[0] with Value = 11101000 00000000 00000000 00000000 and Width = 5
     // and DataList[1] with Value = 11000111 11011000 00000000 00000000 and Width = 9

     //result should be 11101110 00111100
}
```

Comment: Just use bitwise operations on the integers directly

Comment: @cubrr but how can i copy this results to result array? It can be much longer than 4 bytes if i will have 50 or 60 values to processs as example.

Comment: Your explanation of what you're trying to do in the question is unclear. I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cubrr i need to fill result array with bits extracted from Value property of my objects. Number of bits to extract from each object  stored in Width property.

Comment: Number of bits starting from the least or most significant bit?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried, showing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and clearly describe what that code does, and how what it does is different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Please improve this question if you want an answer. As I asked previously, make sure you show exactly what you've tried so far, and include an explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service; you need to make an honest effort yourself to solve the problem, and to provide that effort as a code example in your question.